# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404 in window

Tags: cakephp, ratchet, cakephp-2.6

I am installing `Ratchet Cakephp Plugin` on `XAMPP` on Windows. Installed plugin using composer.
`Cakephp Version-` 2.6.7
`ratchet (Plugin) -` 0.1.*
`ext-libevent` not installed - Actually I don't know how to install it on Windows.
When I started websocket - using coommand

```
.\Console\cake Ratchet.websocket start
```

In browser's console shows

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
Please suggest solution. Thanks in advance.
```

Plugin/Ratchet/Config/botstrap.php

```
Configure::write('Ratchet', [
    'Client' => [
        'retryDelay' => 5000, // Not the best option but it speeds up development
        'maxRetries' => 25, // Keep on trying! (Also not the best option)
    ],
    'Connection' => [
        'websocket' => [
            'address' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 8080,
        ],
        'external' => [
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 80,
            'path' => 'websocket',
            'secure' => false,
        ],
        'keepaliveInterval' => 23, // Why 23? Because NGINX kills after 30 seconds, set to 0 to disable
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting to `ws://localhost:8080` or `ws://127.0.0.1:8080` it sounds like a proxying error

Comment: Yes I did.. same Error.

Comment: When I changed Apache httpd.conf file to NOT Listen to port 8080. It shows following error. WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/websocket' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: It sounds like apache is proxying the websocket connection incorrectly.  Can you post the config?